# Raphael.FreeTransform rotate only

Tags: javascript, raphael

Is that possible with Raphael.FreeTransform to rotate an element, without scaling it?

When I initialize my element with `scale: false, rotate: true` I can only rotate it without scaling and that's OK. I wan't to achieve the same but when `rotate start` event occurs, ie. I want to change the `scale` dynamically from the callback function:

```
    ft = paper.freeTransform(rect, {}, function(ft, events) {
        if (events.indexOf("rotate start") !== -1) {
            ft.setOpts({scale: false});
        }
    });
```

The element is initialized with the following properties:

```
    ft.setOpts({
        keepRatio: false,
        draw: 'bbox',
        snap: {
            rotate: 45
        },
        keepRatio: ['axisX', 'axisY']
    });
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6UqFf/)

Comment: Could you maybe provide a link you jsfiddle? And clarify the question based on that example PLEASE

Comment: @A.S.Roma I tried, but failed with importing Raphael.FreeTransform from github, any idea how to include Raphael.FreeTransform? I also included the broken fiddle in my question.

Comment: what are you trying to move? Do you have to use FreeTransform? Can't you use drag() function?

Comment: Because if you wanna be able just to drag it around, you do not need freeTransform

Comment: @A.S.Roma I decided to use it because it already implements a couple of things I need, "snap to" on rotation, move, scale, drag, etc.

Comment: Can you explain what are you actually trying to do with that rectangle?

Comment: Want to rotate and scale it but not in the same time. If you take a look to http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/, and check in `draw: bbox` a boundary box will appear. What I want to achieve is that to use the boundary box only for scaling and the two orthogonal lines for rotating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually figured out how to do this. Just initialize FreeTransform with the following parameters:

```
    ft.setOpts({
        drag: ['center', 'self'],
        rotate: ['axisY'],
        scale: ['bboxCorners', 'bboxSides'],
        keepRatio: ['bboxCorners'],
        snap: {
            rotate: 45
        },
        draw: 'bbox'
    });
```

http://alias.io/raphael/free_transform/ helped a lot in figuring this out.